# How to reorder a collection

Tags: cakephp, collections, cakephp-3.0

From the following query:

```
$unlocked_ags = $this->Deviceconnections->find()
            ->contain(['Agthemes.Sites'])
            ->where(['request' => 'unlock'])->all();
```

I get the following result. I just kept the useful informations.

```
'items' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Deviceconnection) {

        'id' => (int) 196,
        'agtheme' => object(App\Model\Entity\Agtheme) {

            'id' => (int) 49,
            'site' => object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {

                'id' => (int) 5510,
            },
        },
    },
    (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Deviceconnection) {

        'id' => (int) 197,
        'agtheme' => object(App\Model\Entity\Agtheme) {

            'id' => (int) 44,
            'site' => object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {

                'id' => (int) 64,
            },
        },
    },
    (int) 2 => object(App\Model\Entity\Deviceconnection) {

        'id' => (int) 198,
        'agtheme' => object(App\Model\Entity\Agtheme) {

            'id' => (int) 49,
            'site' => object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {

                'id' => (int) 5510,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    (int) 3 => object(App\Model\Entity\Deviceconnection) {

        'id' => (int) 199,
        'agtheme' => object(App\Model\Entity\Agtheme) {

            'id' => (int) 44,
            'site' => object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {

                'id' => (int) 5682,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    (int) 4 => object(App\Model\Entity\Deviceconnection) {

        'id' => (int) 200,
        'agtheme' => object(App\Model\Entity\Agtheme) {

            'id' => (int) 44,
            'site' => object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {

                'id' => (int) 5682,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    (int) 5 => object(App\Model\Entity\Deviceconnection) {

        'id' => (int) 201,
        'agtheme' => object(App\Model\Entity\Agtheme) {

            'id' => (int) 49,
            'site' => object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {

                'id' => (int) 5510,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    (int) 6 => object(App\Model\Entity\Deviceconnection) {

        'id' => (int) 202,
        },
        'agtheme' => object(App\Model\Entity\Agtheme) {

            'id' => (int) 40,
            },
            'site' => object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {

                'id' => (int) 64,
                },
            },
        },
    }
]
```

But in fact I want to have the list of deviceconnections by site and by agtheme.

I did half the way with the query:

```
$unlocked_ags = $this->Deviceconnections->find()
            ->contain(['Agthemes.Sites'])
            ->where(['request' => 'unlock'])
            ->groupBy('agtheme.site.id');
```

which allows me to group by site.

I would need something like:

```
$unlocked_ags = $this->Deviceconnections->find()
            ->contain(['Agthemes.Sites'])
            ->where(['request' => 'unlock'])
            ->groupBy('agtheme.site.id')
            ->groupBy('agtheme.id');
```

But it seems that I need to write it in a different way.

How to do it?

**EDIT**
I tried something like that:

```
    $unlocked_ags = $this->Deviceconnections->find()
            ->contain(['Agthemes.Sites'])
            ->where(['request' => 'unlock']);

    $unlocked_ags = $unlocked_ags->groupBy('agtheme.site.id');
    $unlocked_ags = new Collection($unlocked_ags);
    $unlocked_ags = $unlocked_ags->groupBy('agtheme.id');
```

That correctly creates grouped arrays but unfortunately, that loose the indexes.

The result is something like:

```
[
    '' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Deviceconnection) {
            ...
```

That's a pity because if I do that:

```
    $unlocked_ags = $this->Deviceconnections->find()
            ->contain(['Agthemes.Sites'])
            ->where(['request' => 'unlock']);

    $unlocked_ags = $unlocked_ags->groupBy('agtheme.site.id');
```

I get:

```
[
    (int) 5510 => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Deviceconnection) {
         ...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to either iterate over the first grouped results and group them again if you want nested results:

```
->groupBy('agtheme.site.id')
->map(function ($data) {
    return collection($data)->groupBy('agtheme.site')->toArray();
})
```

or use a callback to create a custom identifier based on multiple fields, something like:

```
->groupBy(function($row) {
    return $row['agtheme']['id'] . ',' . $row['agtheme']['site']['id'];
})
```

The latter will create string indices like `49,5510`, so be careful when accessing/iterating over the result!

See also **[API > \Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface::groupBy()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Collection.CollectionInterface.html#_groupBy)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway, it's not possible to get something like ['5510' => ['49' => '0' => [...], '1' => [...],...],...] easier to iterate?